# Java global isEmpty() method

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, is-empty

I have an application which uses code that produces various types of objects and data structures, returning them as Object instances, and would like a generic way of establishing whether any of those objects is "empty" (or null).

(This is not a matter of design, or of whether such a method should be used, but a question of optimizing the solution to an existing requirement.)

So, here is a simple go:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Object content)
{
    if (content == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (content instanceof CharSequence)
    {
        return (((CharSequence)content).length() == 0);
    }
    else if (content instanceof Collection<?>)
    {
        return ((Collection<?>)content).isEmpty();
    }
    else if (content instanceof Object[])
    {
        return (((Object[])content).length == 0);
    }
    else  // Use reflection (an exaggeration, for demo purposes)
    {
        try
        {
            Method isEmpty = content.getClass().
                             getDeclaredMethod("isEmpty", (Class<?>[])null);
            if (isEmpty != null)
            {
                Object result = isEmpty.invoke(content, (Object[])null);

                if (result instanceof Boolean)
                {
                    return (Boolean)result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any ideas for potential improvements, in terms of either performance, or coverage?

For instance, reflection could be also used to establish whether the object has a length() or size() method, invoke it and see if the result is 0. (In reality, reflection is probably too much, but I am including it here for completeness.)

Is there a top-level class very commonly used, which has a length() or size() method, instead of the isEmpty() method, to include in the above case, similarly to Collection that has isEmpty()?

Comment: At a glance, the *use* of such a method alone seems like a bad design decision. How will this be used?

Comment: It is used to check the "emptiness" of an Object, returned by a non-changeable method that produces numerous different types of data.

Comment: Why? If you're calling this method you should probably already know what object you're passing to it, just call `isEmpty` on the object itself and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: It is not about passing an Object to the method, but getting an Object from it. The return type is not known, it is just an Object!

Comment: Are you sure you want to define "empty" for arrays as `length==0`? One doesn't normally go around creating zero-length arrays.  In fact, does "empty" have a well-defined meaning for arrays without some extra metadata?

Comment: Obviously, there can't be a generic "isEmpty()" method, so my example is an approximation that serves the range of data types I am using. In this context, "empty" means "no value". What sort of metadata could be associated with an array?

Comment: This is _really depressing._  There's no way to avoid this, at all?  Personally, I'd rather rewrite most of my project than accept a monstrosity like this.

Comment: What if it was not your code but a library you used? But I don't see why it is so weird for a method to return an Object that can be more than one actual type. Maybe not the best of designs, but is it really that rare?

Comment: @PNS returning raw Objects is very un-Javalike.  A strength of Java (which some consider a weakness) is that is is strongly typed.  If calling everything an Object is the preferred style, you/they should consider using a different language.

Comment: @user949300 In principle, you are right, of course. However, it is not the case of "everything", but rather of "some". :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the ugly instanceofs, split up the method into several methods with the same name but different args.  e.g.

```
static boolean isEmpty(Object[] array)
static boolean isEmpty(Collection collection)
static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence cs)
```

Instead of reflection, if you really want your own interface for special objects, declare that interface, and then, for consistency with the above, offer the static utility

```
static boolean isEmpty(IMayBeEmpty imbe);
```

Comment: Not only that, but you can then include some of the commons lang isEmpty methods as well.  Decreasing the amount of code you have to write.

Comment: Still, it smells (doesn't mean it's not justified or unavoidable). But that's the most elegant solution I can think of.

Comment: @Jim You are right that overloading is better than using instanceof, but since the declared return type is Object, only the isEmpty() method with the Object argument will be called. Does the "commons lang" code you mentioned refer to the Apache Commons?

Comment: I concur with PNS.  When virtual method binding is done in an overloaded scenario, it's done at compile time based on the declared types of the parameters.  In this case, if what you're passing into the isEmpty() method is declared as Object, then you'll only ever call isEmpty(Object), regardless of the real type.  You could do some reflection work however here.  See my answer below.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I missed the part where the argument is really defined as an Object, not a Collection, String[] etc...  In that case @Matt is correct, the compiler doesn't know any better.  You'd need instanceof or some sort of double-dispatch.

Comment: Yes, the Apache commons, or jakarta commons: http://commons.apache.org/lang/  While the public method may need to return Object, it can dispatch to protected or private methods that do not.

Answer (score 1):

This method would at least solve your problem of the generic isEmpty(Object) problem.  However, you don't get compile time safety with this, and calling it without the method existing for the exact type requested will yield a runtime error.  Note the "MethodUtils" class is from apache commons-beanutils, though you could easily use reflection directly, but for the sake of simplicity, i'm using beanutils here.

The "invokeExactcMethod" method looks for a static method in the given class with the given name that has the compatible parameters of the object array being passed.  So if the runtime type of the object is ArrayList, it would look for isEmpty(ArrayList) then isEmpty(AbstractList) then isEmpty(List).  It then invokes that method if it can find it, otherwise it throws a NoSuchMethodException.

```
public class MyUtility {
  static boolean isEmpty(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      try {
        return MethodUtils.invokeStaticMethod(
                  MyUtility.class, "isEmpty", new Object[]{object});
      }
      catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
      }
      catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
      }
      catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the "invokeExactStaticMethod" is more deterministic and doesn't use assignment compatibility, but exact signature matching.  That means isEmpty(List) would never match anything because you can't construct anything of that type.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! But wouldn't it be faster to have the instanceofs, especially if the anticipated data types are CharSequence, Collection<?> or array of any type?

Comment: it's likely that MethodUtils is going to cache the answers, but yes, it might be faster.  However than means that everytime you add a new isEmpty method, you have to alter the one with the big IF clause.  With this solution, you simply have to add the new method.  I'm all for less error prone code, and I think this is less error prone.  You'll believe me the first time you try to add a new method and forget the if clause.

Comment: Very reasonable approach. Thanks again.